# Ubuntu GPIO mapping and port configuration

Tags: gpio, ubuntu, spi, raspi-config, config.txt

I turned from Raspbian to Ubuntu 19 32bit on my RPI4 because I need this distribution. I downloaded it using the RPI Imager. 
I had a working pinout on Raspbian, mapped on config.txt for the I2C and SPI display. Where is this config.txt file and how to map the GPIO in Ubuntu? I have read some posts about the installation but this point is not so clear for me. 
Raspi-config is only supported in Ubuntu Mate.
There is one config.txt file on /firmware/ path. Should I modify this file?
What are the proper steps to configure the GPIO?

**EDIT:**

I tried to modify firmware/config.txt, usrconfig.txt and also the config.txt at same location when havins raspi-config installed in Ubuntu Mate. Always the same result...
After modifiying the desired configuration and reboot, the RPI4 enter into a loop trying to boot: the color image blinks, and immediately turns off. Then boot again, a blink of the colored image, turn off... and so on.

The configuration looks like:

```
#i2c, i2s, spi... are deactivated

dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,bus=3,i2c_gpio_sda=23,i2c_gpio_scl=24,i2c_gpio_delay_us=2

# DPI Video Setup
dtoverlay=dpi18
overscan_left=0
overscan_right=0
overscan_top=0
overscan_bottom=0
framebuffer_width=854
framebuffer_height=480
enable_dpi_lcd=1
display_default_lcd=1
dpi_group=2
dpi_mode=87

dpi_output_format=458773
hdmi_timings=854 0 14 4 12 480 0 2 3 9 0 0 0 60 0 32000000 3
```

I am stacked here, so this works perfectly in Raspbian. What is different and needs to be done in ubuntu to get the i2c and DPI running?

Comment: answered https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1644062#p1644062

Comment: Thanks. I posted a reply but seems that I am redirected to stackexchange as the right place. Well, I just edit the question...